# Google Plus Login not working on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, google-plus

Google plus login is working fine on the desktop browser but not on the mobile browser.
link of [website](http://ohyouherodev.elasticbeanstalk.com/)

```
var client_id   = gmail_client_id;
var scope       = gmail_scope;
var apiKey      = google_api_key;


function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
}

function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: client_id, scope: scope, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {

    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        access_token = authResult.access_token;

        makeApiCall();
    } else {

        handleAuthClick();
    }
}

function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: client_id, scope: scope, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
    return false;
}


function makeApiCall() {
    gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
        request.execute(function(resp) {
            checkGoogleUserExist(resp);
        });
    });
}
```

Please suggest the possible issue.

Comment: What is your mobile browser? Maybe try another. For instance using Opera Mobile with Opera Turbo enabled can result in such problems. I've know at least one site I can't use with Turbo on Opera Mobile.

Comment: I am testing on safari browser (iPhone) and Dolphin & Opera on android. All other social elements are working but google is not opening popup.

Comment: Maybe try another plugin for Wordpress for Google Auth

Comment: Thanks for help @Adrian but site is not in wordpress, it is in codeigniter.

Comment: Do you have already a solution to this?

Comment: This is not resolved, finally I customized google+ button :)